# How to compress string by JS?

Tags: javascript

trying writing func for compressing string(2 equal letter become 1). Don't get how to save the progress of compressing(trying different combo with `concat` - unsuccessful). Every time my `for` take full string
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/d2207/pen/BaKXaZy?editors=0012)

```js
let pass = '1122333456';

function CompressPass(string) {
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

    let concisePassword = string.split('');
    const item = string[i];
    const nextItem = string[i + 1];
    console.log(+item, +nextItem);

    if (item === nextItem) {
      concisePassword.splice(i, 1);
      console.log(concisePassword);
    } else {
      console.log('not equal: ', +item, +nextItem);
    }
  };
}
CompressPass(pass);
```

Comment: So you're trying to remove duplicates from the string or are you doing something like `Run Length Encoding`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this help you

```js
let pass = '11223322345666600222222';
function CompressPass (string) {
  string += '-';
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 1; i < string.length; i++) {
    const nextItem = string[i];
    const item = string[i - 1];
     if (item != nextItem){
      str += item;
     }
  };
  return str;
}
console.log(CompressPass(pass))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try 'lz-string' for compressing and de-decompressing string in javascript.

** I used that for compressing local storage data ( as local storage has only a 5MB limit )

** the results may not be visible for shorter strings, but you can try it.

link: https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

example : (from this above-mentioned link )

```
<script language="javascript" src="lz-string.js"></script>

<script>
   var string = "This is my compression test.";
   alert("Size of sample is: " + string.length);

   var compressed = LZString.compress(string);
   alert("Size of compressed sample is: " + compressed.length);

   string = LZString.decompress(compressed);
   alert("Sample is: " + string);
</script>
```